# Is there a way to get a list of newly deletable questions?

Tags: support

My understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) is that a question has to be closed for two weeks before it can be deleted.

Is there a way to get a list of questions that have recently become eligible for deletion, i.e. questions that were closed just a bit over two weeks ago?

Answer (score 5):

Two *days*, rather than two weeks.

If you click on review (on top, next to your name), then on tools, then on close, then choose $7$ days, and then "recently closed", the list will include newly "available" questions.

(Shortcut: Click [here](https://mathoverflow.net/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last7days), and then choose "recently closed".)

Once you reach $20$K you should be able to vote to delete answers with negative scores, and questions just closed with negative scores of, I believe $-3$, or so, without having to wait the two days.

Comment: Thank you; this works!  But I have a (much less critical) followup question:  After I expand the list of recently closed questions, and click on one of those questions to have a look at it, and then hit the back button on my browser --- the list is no longer expanded.  This is a minor annoyance, but still an annoyance.  Is there a way to get a list that I don't have to re-expand every time I look at a question?

Comment: That would be nice. There is no way that I'm aware of. I usually just open new tabs every time I click on something.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg, file a feature request, here or on meta.stackoverflow.com.